# IBM worklight 5 - Unable to install plug-in

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to run the IBM Worklight plugin in eclipse classic, but I'm running into some errors:

- First of all, I want to update eclipse, but it seems to take over 20 hours to do so. Is there another possibility to update to the latest software? I need to do this in order to install ibm worklight.
- Secondly, I'm receiving this errorcode:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse 4.2 Dependencies 1.0.0.v20120615_1503 (com.ibm.rational.dependency.eclipse42.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120615_1503)

I'm loading the IBM worklight from a .zip file. Hopefully I have given you enough information to help me.

**Update 1:** I also tried using eclipse EE for IDE. Then I got this error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AJAX Web Tools 1.0.0.v20120731_1538 (com.ibm.wdt.webtools.ajax.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120731_1538)

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the developer version of Worklight or a licensed. I would suggest using the Eclipse marketplace and searching for the Worklight plug in. Typically this is a smoother way of installing the plug in. Where did you get the zip files of the plug in? If it was directly from IBM, make sure it is the newest version which is the 5.0.5.1 (crazy versions, I know) If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Worklight supports Eclipse versions 4.2, 3.7, and 3.6. For the Marketplace client use Juno, Indigo or Helios Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. (taken from: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-developer-edition#.UTTUNoeH7zs).
If you use other versions of eclipse you'll probably face installation problems.
Also check the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option in "Install new software" wizard.
Regarding upgrading eclipse as far as I know there is no way to upgrade eclipse to the next version, you must download and install desired eclipse version.